# What is the minimum value dataset for MYRRIX SERVING LAYER

Tags: myrrix

I am okay wit the example data set from audioscrobbler, which is totals in 75K users and 50K items. But mine is to tiny ,since I am in the start of the road. So will be happy to know what are the minimum data set used in Myrrix. The reason of asking that is a warning:

INFO: Converged
Aug 14, 2013 10:15:41 PM net.myrrix.online.generation.DelegateGenerationManager$RefreshCallable runFactorization
INFO: Factorization complete
Aug 14, 2013 10:15:41 PM net.myrrix.online.generation.Generation recomputeSolver
WARNING: X'*X or Y'*Y has small inf norm (0.9254986853162671); try decreasing model.als.lambda
Aug 14, 2013 10:15:41 PM net.myrrix.online.generation.DelegateGenerationManager$RefreshCallable call
WARNING: Unable to compute a valid generation yet; waiting for more data

thank you for everybody who can assist

Answer (score 1):

I was able to ingest a file with 10 lines of associations only. 
By the way, Myrrix is migrating to Oryx now, you may ask Sean Owen on https://groups.google.com/a/cloudera.org/forum/#!forum/oryx-user